# Python sorting on the fly conversion to custom class

Tags: python, sorting, kdtree

I am working with Autodesk Maya and PyMel, which has custom classes for representation of its vertices. Within that MeshVertex class is a Point class, which specifies the x, y, z coordinates of the vertex. I am trying to produce a KD-Tree of vertices, which I can then search through to find the nearest neighboring vertex of a given point.

Since I have several hundred thousand vertices in even the simplest cases I really don't want to iterate over them to produce a dictionary and a list of coordinates and then construct the KD-Tree from the coordinates. I would prefer to provide a KD-Tree constructor method the MeshVertex list and have it generate a class that pairs the coordinates it has to pull from those two, along with the MeshVertex object, on the fly as its building the KD-Tree.

I am working from a simple KD-Tree construction algorithm I pulled off Wikipedia, but I'm stuck at the part where it sorts the list. I don't know how to implement a custom sort for a class that sorts by the 3D coordinates. I suspect I have to define a **sort** and **itemgetter** for the class, but I don't know how. Also, is there a way to specify the class such that the len() method will properly get the length of the location (3D coordinate of the custom class). This is all I've come up with so far (mostly from wikipedia):

```
class Node(namedtuple('Node', 'location left_child right_child')):
    def __repr__(self):
        return pformat(tuple(self))

# This is the custom wrapper for MeshVertex
class vert(namedtuple('Vert', 'location vertex')):
    def __repr__(self):
        return pformat(tuple(self))

def kdtree(point_list, depth=0):
    try:
        vertex = point_list[0]
        vPoint = vertex.getPosition( space='world' )
        pos = ( vPoint.x, vPoint.y, vPoint.z )
        vertex = Vert(
            location=pos,
            vertex=vertex
        )
        k = len( vertex ) # assumes all points have the same dimension
    except IndexError as e: # if not point_list:
        return None
    # Select axis based on depth so that axis cycles through all valid values
    axis = depth % k

    # Sort point list and choose median as pivot element
    point_list.sort( point_list, key=itemgetter(axis))
    median = len( vertex ) // 2 # choose median

    # Create node and construct subtrees
    return Node(
        location=point_list[median],
        left_child=kdtree(point_list[:median], depth + 1),
        right_child=kdtree(point_list[median + 1:], depth + 1)
    )
```